# How do I create a temporary JMS queue in Spring?

Tags: spring-jms

For request/response, I need a temporary queue for the replies. I'd like to create a queue and keep it open all the time (instead of, say, creating a new queue for every request using `SessionCallback.doInJms()`).

How do I do that with Spring's JMS support?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do this, so I create a workaround. This class will keep a session and connection open until the context is destroyed. That way, you can be sure that you will get every reply. Other code often sends the message, opens a reply queue and then sometimes fails to see the reply because it was sent before the reply queue could be opened by the sender.

Usage:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate replyJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate result = new JmsTemplate(jmsConnectionFactory());
    result.setDefaultDestination(replyQueueProvider().getQueue());
    result.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
    return result;
}

@Bean
public QueueProvider replyQueueProvider() {
    QueueProvider result = new QueueProvider(jmsConnectionFactory());
    result.init(); // Must call manually; no @PostConstruct!
    return result;
}
```

Implementation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils;

public class QueueProvider {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueProvider.class);

    private static final AtomicInteger COUNT = new AtomicInteger();

    private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private String queueName;
    private boolean isTemporary;
    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;
    private Queue queue;
    private boolean transacted;
    private int acknowledgeMode = Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE;

    public QueueProvider(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String queueName) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    public QueueProvider(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.isTemporary = true;
        this.queueName = "TemporaryQueue-" + COUNT.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void setTransacted(boolean transacted) {
        this.transacted = transacted;
    }

    public boolean getTransacted() {
        return transacted;
    }

    public void setAcknowledgeMode(int acknowledgeMode) {
        this.acknowledgeMode = acknowledgeMode;
    }

    public int getAcknowledgeMode() {
        return acknowledgeMode;
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            session = connection.createSession(transacted, acknowledgeMode);

            log.debug("Opening queue {}", queueName);
            if (isTemporary) {
                queue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
            } else {
                queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UncategorizedJmsException("Error creating queue " + queueName, e);
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void close() {
        log.debug("Closing queue {}", queueName);
        queue = null;
        JmsUtils.closeSession(session);
        JmsUtils.closeConnection(connection);
    }

    public Queue getQueue() {
        if(null == queue) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Either init() wasn't called or close() was already called");
        }
        return queue;
    }
}
```